# passing data from textview of activity 1 through textview of activity2

Tags: android

How to pass value of textview form one activity going to the other activity?

I have a scoring on my game that is shown on a textview and after it increment it will intent to the next activity. but the value of score from the first activity doesn't show on the textview of the second activity.

this is my code for my first activity

```
final TextView score2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvscore2);
    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDog);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText etDog1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDog);
            String Dog = etDog1.getText().toString();

            if (Dog.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) {
                global.score += 10;


                score2.setText(String.valueOf(global.score));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                        sound1_3pig.class);

                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

            } else if (global.score <= 0) {
                global.score += 0;
                score2.setText(String.valueOf(global.score));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                global.score -= 5;
                score2.setText(String.valueOf(global.score));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

I want to display the result of the score activity 1 to the textview of the second activity

this is my second activity

```
final TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvscore1);
    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCat);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText etCat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCat);
            String Cat = etCat.getText().toString();
            if (Cat.equalsIgnoreCase("cat")) {

                global.score += 10;
                score2.setText(String.valueOf(global.score));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                        sound1_3pig.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();

            } else if (global.score <= 0) {
                global.score += 0;
                score2.setText(String.valueOf(global.score));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                global.score -= 5;
                score2.setText(String.valueOf(global.score));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: How you are passing it?

Comment: you can pass it through the `intent` which you are using to start the second activity. you should post the relevant codes of both the activities in your question, so that we can tell you where you may possibly be going wrong.

Comment: @PoonamAnthony I already post my code

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this.

Activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("Score", 20);

startActivity(i);
```

Activity 2:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int score = i.getIntExtra("Score", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

As your second activity inflates a new layout, you need to explicitly pass your value from the first to the second activity and initialize it's TextView using this value.

Activity 1:

```
void goToSecondActivity() {
    String value = mTextView.getText();
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), YourSecondClass.class);
    in.putExtra("score", value);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Activity 2:

```
void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    String score = getIntent().getStringExtra("score", "No score.");
    mTextView.setText(score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is also similar to what the others have suggested. try this, I have added some extra statements within your code(I presumed you want to send the value of variable `score` to the next activity, you can replace it with the variable you want to send) :

first activity:

```
score2.setText(String.valueOf(score));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,
                    sound1_3pig.class);
myIntent.putExtra("Score", global.score);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

second activity:

put this in the onCreate() method of the second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("Score",0);
```

so now you will get the value of score from the previous activity in the second activity. then you can set it in the textView you want to display it in by calling

```
textView.setText(score);
```

Comment: after I put the `Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("Score",0);` on my next activity, what should I do next?

Comment: then you initialize your textview by using findViewById(). I hope that is what you must be doing?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
this link might help you.